# fillna(0) first but NaN value appears in iloc

Tags: python, pandas, nan

```
df1.fillna(0)
Montant vente   Marge
0   778283.75   13.63598
1   312271.20   9.26949
2   163214.65   14.50288
3   191000.20   9.55818
4   275970.00   12.76534
...     ...     ...
408     2999.80     14.60610
409     390.00  0.00000
410     699.00  26.67334
411     625.00  30.24571
412     0.00    24.79797

x = df1.iloc[:,1:3] # 1t for rows and second for columns
x

Marge
0   13.63598
1   9.26949
2   14.50288
3   9.55818
4   12.76534
...     ...
408     14.60610
409     NaN
410     26.67334
411     30.24571
412     24.79797

413 rows × 1 columns
```

Why does the line 409 has a 0.000value first and then after iloc, it has NaN?

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: `fillna` does not mutate the dataframe unless you give the `inplace=True` option.  Otherwise you need to do `df1 = df1.fillna(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn which functions mutate the data frame and which doesn't. For example `fillna` does not mutate the dataframe. Instead you can use `inplace=True`

```
df1 = df1.fillna(0)
```

or

```
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```